# Put two values on top of each bar in a histogram

Tags: r, histogram, plotrix

I have the following data,

> SampleID  Pos Dep Pvalues
>   sample_1    849 62  0.02755358
>   sample_1    859 63  0.07406833
>   sample_1    864 63  0.00351564
>   sample_1    883 60  0.02780868
>   sample_1    893 58  0.00451450
>   sample_1    895 58  0.03600795
>   sample_2    54  66  0.11864407
>   sample_2    55  67  0.01515152
>   sample_2    71  91  0.02712367
>   sample_2    78  97  0.00077325

I have generated a histogram of P-values with the frequency values on top of each bar. Below, is the code

> pval_at_site <- read.table("samples.pval")
>   s <- hist(pval_at_site$Pvalues, xlab="Pval",cex=0.8)
>   text(s$mids,s$counts,s$count,srt=90,pos = 3,offset=1,cex=0.6)

Now, what I would like to do is, along with P-value frequency, add the number of samples on top of each bar.

For example, if I have, say, 1000 datapoints in the first interval, and these values come from 20 unique samples I would want my plot to say "1000,20" on top of the first bar.

Please let me know how I should go about this. Hope I have made myself clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the number of unique values, and generate text labels outside the `hist()` computations. There are more efficient ways to do this split-apply-combine operation (look into `dplyr` and `data.table`), but the code below implements it with minimal changes:

```
data= "SampleID Pos Dep Pvalues
sample_1 849 62 0.02755358
sample_1 859 63 0.07406833
sample_1 864 63 0.00351564
sample_1 883 60 0.02780868
sample_1 893 58 0.00451450
sample_1 895 58 0.03600795
sample_2 54 66 0.11864407
sample_2 55 67 0.01515152
sample_2 71 91 0.02712367
sample_2 78 97 0.00077325"

pval_at_site <- read.table(text=data, header=TRUE)
s <- hist(pval_at_site$Pvalues, xlab="Pval",cex=0.8)

# get a vector of each bin
bins <- cut(pval_at_site$Pvalues, breaks=s$breaks)

# get sum of unique values by bin value based on hist() output
count.samples <- tapply(pval_at_site$SampleID, bins, function(x) length(unique(x)))
count.samples[is.na(count.samples)] <- 0  ## remove NAs from empty bins

# generate text labels by combining both values
tags <- paste(s$count, count.samples, sep=" - ")

text(s$mids,s$counts,tags,srt=90,pos = 3,offset=1,cex=0.6)
```